# Parse error - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought Aurora wordpress theme from Themeforest.
When I'm trying to install it, I have parse error: unexpected ':' in functions.php file on line 361.

Functions.php line 361

```
$customizer_template_setting = get_theme_mod('aurora_post_layout') ?: 'default';
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the shortened ternary syntax, that is only available in PHP 5.3 and newer.
You should check your PHP version (and in case update it, recommended!).

That syntax is equivalent to:

`$customizer_template_setting = get_theme_mod('aurora_post_layout') ? get_theme_mod('aurora_post_layout') : 'default';`

The extreme solution if you cannot update your PHP version would be to replace that line.